# XSD validation error human readable

Tags: c#

I want to be able to validate a XML against a XSD and generate user readable errors, for example, including XSD documentation tag.

I just wanted to know if C# provides this in a easy, elegant and non-painful way, otherwise I'll parse down the error and find the node within XSD.

Answer (score 0):

XML Schema itself doesn't provide a way to do what you want!

XML Schema is not meant to communicate to humans in a human manner. Forget about it.